# Unable to pass parameter to service in Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony

I am use a parameter in my service with Symfony 3.3 but I keep getting the error.

**Error**

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\AutowiringFailedException]
>     Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface": argument "$api_endpoint" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.

**config.yml**

```
services:
app.security.login_form_authenticator:
    class: AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
    autowire: true
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
app.service.api_interface:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface
    arguments:
      $api_endpoint: "%endpoint test%"

_defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

**ApiInterface.php**

```
use Unirest;

class ApiInterface
{

private $api_endpoint;

public function __construct(string $api_endpoint)
{
    $this->timeout = 1;

    echo 'form apiinterface construct: ' . $api_endpoint;

}
```

Any help appreciated feel like I am going round in circles in what should be a simple job!

Comment: May be the indentation is not enough. Can you try with 4 whitespaces for your parameter

Comment: Parameters don't usually have spaces in them, and although it looks like it runs OK, you might want to 'lint' it - `bin/console lint:yaml app`  (or other path to files, like src/).  If you are auto-wring, you may prefer to call the service by class name, and not the 'app.service.api_interface' alias.

Comment: The alias isn't reconized by the config at the end. So effectively, I think the problem is the alias because Symfony load 2 services. The `app.service.api_interface` is correct but not `AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface`

Comment: Interesting.  I copied/pasted your code into a sample 3.3.10 project and it all worked as expected.  Are you sure your actual ApiInterface code matches what you posted in your question?  Or maybe a typo in your services.yaml file.

Comment: Could you show us where and how your app.service.api_interface-service is used ? Is it used as argument from another service ? Is it got with $container->get("app.service.api_interface") ?

Comment: Try moving your own service definitions after `_defaults` configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 different services :`app.service.api_interface` and `AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface`. The first is good configured, the second is not.

If you necessarily need the `app.service.api_interface` service, you can change your configuration in order to have the first as an alias of the second like this :

```
app.service.api_interface: '@AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface'
AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface:
    arguments:
        $api_endpoint: "%endpoint test%"
```

With your config, you do not configure the `AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface` service, but you configure the `app.service.api_interface` service.
With my suggestion, you configure the 2 services.

If you do not need `app.service.api_interface` service, you can only let one service :

```
AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface:
    arguments:
        $api_endpoint: "%endpoint test%"
```

This declaration overrides the `AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface`service.
You can override any service that's imported by using its id (class name) below : It's preferable to move this overriding below the `AppBundle\` declaration.

Final file can be like this :

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    app.security.login_form_authenticator: '@AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator'
        # autowire: true #Optional, already set in _defaults
        # arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'] # Optional because of autowiring

    app.service.api_interface: '@AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface' 
    AppBundle\Service\ApiInterface:
        arguments:
            $api_endpoint: "%endpoint test%"
```

[Documentation : manually wiring arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments)

[Documentation : explicitly configuring services and arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments)

In addition, I suggest you to remove the space of the parameter name `%endpoint test%` (and rename it to `%endpoint_test%` for example)

Comment: Moving things around worked. I ended up having the one service and manually wiring it in. Thanks you,

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Just in time too, I was about to launch my screen out the window :-)

Comment: Happy to know that it is useful for you :-)